# bootstrap: Выравнивание заголовка таблицы по центру

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Имеется вот такая картина:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как выравнять заголовок h2 по центру таблицы?
Пробовал задавать как стиль, как класс, добавить в отдельный `row`.
По центру текст отображается только при определенном разрешении. Если открыть страницу во весь экран, то всегда "съезжает" текст.

**Html код**

```html
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2 class="text-center">Выстрелы</h2>
      <table class="table" id="shipField">
        <thead>
            <th class="cell no_border" *ngFor="let letter of alphabet" >{{ letter }}</th>
        </thead>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of this.battleFieldService.shipField; let i = index" >
          <td class="cell no_border">{{ i }}</td>
          <td *ngFor="let cell of row">
              <app-cell [status]=cell.status [x]=cell.x [y]=cell.y></app-cell>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

**UPDATE**

```html
<table class="table" id="shootField">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <thead>
                <th class="text-center" colspan="11">Выстрелы</th>
              </thead>
            </tr>
              <th class="cell no_border" *ngFor="let letter of alphabet" >{{ letter }}</th>
          </thead>
          <tr *ngFor="let row of this.shootService.shotField; let i = index">
              <td class="cell no_border">{{ i }}</td>
              <td *ngFor="let cell of row">
                <app-cell id="cell" [status]=cell.status [x]=cell.x [y]=cell.y (click)="shoot(cell)"></app-cell>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавьте в заголовок самой таблицы как отдельный TR <thead><tr><th class="center" colspan="11">Выстрелы</th></tr><tr><th class="cell ...</th></tr></tr></thead>...

Comment: @Konst, добавил. выравнивание стало по левому краю и вся таблица "слиплась"

Comment: задайте правильный colspan на основе размера вашего массива alphabet и используйте свой класс для центровки, я просто прописал class="center" для наглядности

Comment: @Konst, все равно коверкает таблицу и не совсем по центру получается

Comment: выложите свой полученный финальный фрагмент html для демонстрации, у меня ничего не коверкает. возможно у вас стили другие накладываются на элементы

Comment: @Konst, обновил пост

Comment: <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align: center !important;" colspan="{{alphabet.length}}">Выстрелы</th>
            </tr>
              <th class="cell no_border" *ngFor="let letter of alphabet" >{{ letter }}</th></tr>
          </thead>

Comment: @Konst, заработало, только пришлось паддинг прописать, потому что визуально не по центру было. Оформите, пожалуйста как ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

добавьте в заголовок самой таблицы как отдельный TR, примерно так:

```
<thead> 
    <tr> 
        <th style="text-align: center !important;" colspan="{{alphabet.length}}">Выстрелы</th>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <th class="cell no_border" *ngFor="let letter of alphabet" >{{ letter }}</th>
    </tr> 
</thead>
```

стиль заголовка можно переопределить через свой класс по необходимости.

Answer (score 0):

Оформите название таблицы в тег `<caption>Корабли</caption>`, вставив его сразу после тега `<table>`

```html
<table>
    <caption>Корабли</caption>
    <tr>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
        <td>ячейка</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: не сработало, теперь выравнивается по левому краю